# A medical degree in fashion from France. What does that mean?

Tags: quotes

The full sentence is

> Oh, wait, it's a she. Still, what does she know about - oh, wait. She has a medical degree. In fashion. From France.

by GLaDOS in Portal 2. Is that some idiom or meme? I've googled about this but nothing found...in Portal 2 Wiki, many people voted this quotes so I think it has some meaning which I dont know.

EDIT:
Sorry for missing context. It appeared in the test chamber 15 of game Portal 2. Before she said like that, she had said

> That jumpsuit you're wearing looks stupid. That's not me talking, it's right here in your file. On other people it looks fine, but right here a scientist has noted that on you it looks 'stupid.'

and then

> Well, what does a neck-bearded old engineer know about fashion? He probably - Oh, wait. It's a she. Still, what does she know? Oh wait, it says she has a medical degree. In fashion! From France!

What I meant about many people voted is [this](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1053061). It's quotes.net ...? I don't know well about it but it shows that 4 people liked this quote. And I played this game more than 400 times at least but I have no idea why she said like "... a medical degree. In fashion! From France!". I thought it was something like pun..

Comment: This is more of a question about general culture. You will probably get better results on Quora or Reddit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a joke about the extreme qualifications of the person assessing Chelle's jumpsuit. GLaDOS at first suggests the assessment of the jumpsuit looking "stupid" was written by an old male scientist who doesn't know anything about fashion in the first place. But then it's revealed that the person is actually extremely qualified, being 1) a woman, 2) highly educated 3) educated in fashion, and 4) taught in France, a stereotypically fashionable country. The joke is that the scientist supposedly judging the jumpsuit is qualified to an *absurd* degree, to the point of holding a medical degree in fashion, which isn't something one can get a medical degree in - a medical degree is a very high academic credential, the joke is the absurdity of attaining such a credential in the field of fashion.